# What is the alternative to getActionBar()?

Tags: android

When I try to use `getActionBar()` it says it is deprecated, so that means by going forward we are not allowed to use `getActionBar()`.

Which is the best way to learn how to create Tabs in the current situation?

Comment: Use the new `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you should create this, because Fragment Tabs using 
ActionBar is now deprecated. This is new way to create your actionbar with 
Material Design. to use this you need to add dependencies in your build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```

create toolbar app_bar.xml file, you can give the name you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Make sure, you selected theme in styles.xml with

```
"Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

after that, you need to initialize this toolbar in your mainActivity.xml layout file, for that include this,

```
 <include
        android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_toolbar"/>
```

then in the MainActivity, you need to make instance of Toolbar toolbar. then,  after setContentView()
add following with your

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `appcompat`, the correct method is `getSupportActionBar()`