# Material Action Bar Missing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I promise this isn't a duplicate question. I've seen a bunch of other questions on this topic that are similar but they all seem to be using appCompat, and none answer my question.

### The Problem

I'm running into a problem where I can't get the actionbar to show if I use the Material theme Theme.Material.Light compiling against the v21 APIs in AOSP. Everything shows up very material looking but there's no actionbar.

### What I've Tried

- I had the app output `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and `Build.VERSION.RELEASE`. The results were as `21` and `5.0.1` respectively as expected.
- I switched to using a different themes. `Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar` didn't have an actionbar. `Theme.Material.NoActionBar` showed a smaller dialog-like window of my app without an actionbar but with a top title bar. `Theme.Holo.Light` shows an actionbar but it gives me all the Holo theme icons and animations.
- I tried getting the actionbar programmatically with `getActionBar().show();` but got a null pointer exception.
- I created a test project in Eclipse with a copy in of the folders in my problem project for values, layouts, and drawables. The test app shows the actionbar. This leads me to think the problem doesn't lie with those folders.
- I tried moving the style to the AndroidManifest to see if there was a conflict with another values folder or something, but still no actionbar.

### The Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <service android:name=".ServiceA" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.qualcomm.listen.sva.LOCAL_SERVICE" />
            <action android:name="com.qualcomm.listen.sva.REMOTE_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".ux.dev.ActivityC"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeA.Theme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ux.dev.ActivityB"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeA.Theme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ux.dev.ActivityA"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeA.Theme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ux.dev.ActivityD"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeA.Theme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ux.dev.ActivityE"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeA.Theme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ux.dev.ActivityF"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeA.Theme" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".BootupReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".ScreenOnoffReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity
        android:name=".ux.user.UserActivityA"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_keyphrase"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ux.user.UserActivityB"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_select_action" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ux.user.UserActivityC"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The problem is with ux.user.UserActivityC no having the actionbar.

Comment: "I tried getting the actionbar programmatically with getActionBar().show(); but got a null pointer exception" -- that should only occur if there is no action bar, due to theme.

Comment: "I tried getting the actionbar programmatically with getActionBar().show();" you shouldv'e tried `getSupportActionBar().show()`

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. Any idea why the applied theme (Theme.Material, Theme.Material.Light) wouldn't have an actionbar on 5.0.1?

Comment: They do have an action bar. Something else is wrong. Are you *really* sure that you're actually running the code with these themes?

Comment: i have given you solution, this is perfectly tested by me.. let me know whether it works for you or not!

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I double checked by changing a string in the code and the correct string shows in the app. After adding a theme with an actionbar in the manifest, is there anything you can think of that could mess with an actionbar showing up app-wide?

Comment: @CommonsWare I figured out the problem. I was making my app in an old AOSP build (v20) and installing the app on a device running a newer version of android. If you have any idea why compiling using an older AOSP build caused me to not have the material actionbar, I'd love to hear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your style.xml file (Which will be style.xml(v21))

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
</style>
```

Then make sure, you are extending your activity with

```
MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

**This will show actionBar even if you are using android:Theme.Material.Light**

Moreover it is recommended that in material design, you should use Toolbar widget.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />
```

refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30400594/3498931 , how you can create toolbar. It act as ActionBar in Material Design.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Doesn't adding a `ActionBarActivity` require importing a support library? I'm trying to avoid that since I don't need to support v20 or lower.

Comment: yes You need to add dependencies in your build.gradle file .. compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0"

Comment: and this is the upgraded version of library which supports material design.

Comment: in androix, replace compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0 with implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0' and instead of ActionBarActivity use AppCompatActivity