# How to fasten images on the left and right sides ActionBar?

Tags: android

I am creating custom `ActionBar` with two images and text. The first `ImageView` (icon) shall be fixed to the left, next to it the `TextView`, second `ImageView` (image) to be fixed to the right. The size of images and text must be the same on all screens. How can I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="6">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="mAPP"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="@dimen/actionbar_title_text_size" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_text"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_image" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use this example to use a tool bar as the action bar, you can modify the toolbar as a normal layout: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443403/toolbar-and-contextual-actionbar-with-appcompat-v7

Comment: you can use Relativelayout ... and set the gravity to left and right on your views.. its simple.. or use the toolbar.. its Material design way .. and best way.. you can implement here visit this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30400594/3498931

Comment: thanks to all, i solved this problem