# When to set a Tool Bar as an Action Bar when using AppCompat v21?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

Google introduced the Tool Bar widget in [AppCompat v21](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).  I understand that you can assign the Tool Bar as the Action Bar (via setSupportActionBar()) in your Activity.

What is the advantage of installing your Tool Bar as the action bar instead of using standalone Tool Bars in your layout all the time?  Are there things a Tool Bar can do when its installed as the action bar that it can't do when is used standalone?

The [linked article](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) touches on this topic a bit: "Use a Toolbar as an Action Bar when you want to use the existing Action Bar facilities (such as menu inflation and selection, ActionBarDrawerToggle, and so on) but want to have more control over its appearance."

... but they used the catchall "and so on".  What other capabilities does an Action Bar provide that one misses out on with a standalone tool bar?

Comment: if using toolbar in the actionbar you get the overflow menu and any actionbar related stuff ie. up button, nav bar etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30400594/3498931 .. refer this answer it explains how can you create Toolbar appBar as ActionBar..

Comment: @tycjz, thanks.  I've managed to make the overflow menu appear in a standalone tool bar.   I also noticed that the tab-based and list-based navigation modes are deprecated in ActionBar.   So far the only other ActionBar-only feature i've seen that's not deprecated is the up button, and I think I can replicate the up button functionality using the tool bar's optional "navigation button" feature (though it appears to require more work than the Action Bar equivalent, and would opt to use Action Bar directly if I wanted the up function).

Comment: the toolbar is an actionbar that is highly customizable which is why everything in the actionbar is deprecated now. toolbar you can pretty much do anything you want where actionbar you were limited with what you got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage of using a toolbar as a part of the UI component is that u can add animations to it.... for instance i think u might have used play store before in that when you open up an app u could see a video of the app or a screenshot of the app display upon scrolling u could see the ActionBar appearing from nowhere....these kind of animations are not possible if you are using an ActionBar in your application... Another instance of using a toolbar is u can hide it when ever u need to... upon scrolling a list view you can hide that so u could provide more room for your content... this cant be done with an ActionBar...

I think that summarizes the essence of ToolBar over ActionBar

**EDIT 1 :**
Sorry Google changed its play store UI so u will not find that so i would suggest u to look into an app called `Zomato`